# Crystal report skip First Group and apply only second group?

Tags: visual-studio, group-by, crystal-reports, formula

I have two groups in my crystal report. The First Group is by employee profession and second group is by employee branch. I am able to successfully suppress the groups based on conditions. The problem is if I suppress the branch it works fine as it is child group but when I suppress the Profession it doesn't work properly. It keeps showing me redundant branch as same profession exist in all of the branches. So it is keep repeating the branch for different profession. I actually want to use single group by based on condition on same report.

Is there any way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Apply the group suppress logic (in reverse) to the group selection formula.
That would ensure that when a group level 1 is removed, all levels below it are also removed.

Or, if you wish to stay with the section suppress approach, the suppress logic of level 1 needs to be included in the suppress logic of level 2.

Your last sentence is not clear. Perhaps you need to change your grouping logic. Or perhaps you need to use a CrossTab.